# 503 Service Unavailable for frontend of Magento 1.8 Apache 2.4 EC2 Bitnami

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, magento, amazon-ec2, bitnami

I have a hosting in EC2 Amazon Bitnami where I migrated the Magento 1.8. After enhancing the performance, like enabling Flat Catalog when I did the reindexing my website gets down and can't access. I still have to restart the server. I found out that the mysql is exhausting the resources.

Can someone give me tips on how I can prevent the exhaustion of my server?

Thank you!

Comment: Bitnami Developer here. What are the characteristics of the your EC2 instance? Please note that your Magento web site might not work in you don't have enough resources. Could you please take a look to the advices  in the section `In case of performance problems` of the Troubleshooting guide below?

[Performance TroubleShooting](https://docs.bitnami.com/bch/how-to/troubleshoot-servers-bch/#create-a-helpdesk-ticket)

Comment: Hi @Juan I have a m3.large instance type, 100gb volume size. It's working fine though but I can't reindex because that's where it exhausted the resources. Thanks for the link! I'll check it.